# How can I allow an Ant property file to override the value set in another?

Tags: ant

I have an ant file that does the following:

```
<property file="project.properties" description="Project configuration properties"/>
<property file="build-defaults.properties" description="default build configuration."/>
<property file="build.properties" description="local build configuration overrides"/>
```

I want to have defaults set in build-defaults.properties (which is checked in to SCM) but allow developers to override values in a local build.properties so that they can work with local paths.

The problem is, it doesn't seem to be working; I've set this up, created an override in build.properties, but the value of my path remains the one set in build-defaults.properties. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The initial problem with your set up is that you've got `build.properties` and `build-defaults.properties` reversed.

[Ant Properties](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html) are set once and then can never be overridden.  That's why setting any property on the command line via a `-Dproperty=value` will always override anything you've set in the file; the property is set and then nothing can override it.

So the way you want this set up is:

```
<property file="build.properties" description="local build configuration overrides"/>
<property file="project.properties" description="Project configuration properties"/>
<property file="build-defaults.properties" description="default build configuration."/>
```

This way:

1. Anything set at the command line takes precedence over build.properties
2. Anything set in build.properties overrides other values
3. etc. on down the line.

Answer (score 17):

Actually **ant properties may be overriden**. See the documentation of the [property task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html):

> Normally property values can not be changed, once a property is set,
>   most tasks will not allow its value to be modified.

One of the tasks that are able to override the property value is `script`. Also any custom task may use this backdoor. Other proposals are in question [Ant loadfile override property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358525/ant-loadfile-override-property). This is against the spirit of ant and usually unnecessary. But it's good to know that, because I just had an opposite problem: why the property value changed although *it is immutable*.

Here is a sample target that uses script task to change the value of a property. It shows the basic methods to work with properties. All methods are described in Ant Api which is not available online. You need to download the [Ant Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manualdownload.cgi). In its `api` directory there is the api documentation.

```
  <target name="t1">
    <property name="a" value="one" />
    <script language="javascript">
      sProp = project.getProperty("a");
      sProp = sProp.replace("e", "ly");
      project.setProperty("a", sProp);
      project.setNewProperty("a", "new value");
    </script>
    <property name="a" value="two" />
    <echo>a=${a}</echo>
  </target>
```

**How to easily setup the `script` task?** Making the script task running with `beanshell` language is a bit tricky and non-trivial, but it's explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12653680/772981). However as [Rebse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130683/rebse) noted, using `javascript` language is supported out of the box in jdk 6.

Comment: Setting up script task is not tricky when using jdk >= 1.6, means no extra jars needed (Bean Scripting Framework and stuff..) anymore as the jdk ships with a javascript engine already (based on Rhino 1.6R2). Just use script task with javascript.. Alternatively use Groovy which needs only one jar

Comment: @Rebse, you made my day with the `javascript` suggestion. It works like a charm! I edited my answer to include it. For other languages, even if they need just one jar, the link is still useful.

Comment: shameless promotion alert ;-) Ant addon Flaka (http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) makes many scripting parts obsolet (property overwrite, loops ..), also only one jar needed. Beside Flaka i use Groovy alot - not only for ant scripting.

Comment: not quite your problem, but fitting to the answer: here is how **`<loadproperties ...` overrides duplicate entries defined inside of the file by default** :-/ ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358525/ant-loadfile-override-property#comment84608671_5358525

Answer (score 6):

Ant property can't be overwritten unless using macro and javascript plug-in to do:

Step 1: define a macro function to overwrite property

```
 <!--overwrite property's value-->
    <macrodef name="set" >
        <attribute name="name"/>
        <attribute name="value"/>
        <sequential>
            <script language="javascript">
                <![CDATA[
                project.setProperty("@{name}", "@{value}");
                ]]>
            </script>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>
```

Step 2: use the macro in the ant xml

```
<set
    name="your_target_property"
    value="your_value" or "${another_property}"     
</set>
```