# Ant loadfile override property

Tags: variables, ant, properties, flaka

I'm trying to use the Ant task `<loadfile>` in a loop to parse the contents of a file. I have something like

```
<loadfile srcFile="@{some.input}" property="my.property">
```

Since Ant properties are immutable, this doesn't work for me. I need 'my.property' to update on every iteration. Is there a way to achieve this? I know Ant-contrib has a `<var>` task but I'm not sure how to use `<loadfile>` with it.

Any recommendations?

Thanks.

Comment: not quite your problem, but: surprisingly in my env (ant 1.9.4) **`<loadfile src="..." encoding="..." />` did override a property that was defined twice inside of it** :-( unfortunately this caused some prod changes intended for a test system! obviously overriding in the same file seems to be a default :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Ant plugin Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) provides a let task, allowing to overwrite existing properties or variables like that =

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">

<property name="my.property" value="value"/>
<fl:let> my.property ::= 'anothervalue'</fl:let>

</project>
```

So no need to unset first and set afterwards. btw. Flaka has a unset task also ;-)

Answer (score 7):

```
<loadfile property="foo" srcfile="bar.txt"/>

 ... do some actions, perhaps in a <for> loop ...

<var name="foo" unset="true"/>
```

You can then use `foo` again in `<loadfile>`

Comment: To clarify the var task is in the AntContrib stuff and it works with standard properties.

Comment: This worked great! I placed the `<var />` element just before `<loadfile/>` and it works every time. Essentially makes the property mutable. Great hack when needed! Used it in a `<retry/>` operation.

Answer (score 1):

Ant contrib also has a var task that unsets.

Lucks: It is convention to accept one of the answers so people know the question is resolved.  I recommend you accept Gilbert's since he post a correct answer first.

Comment: In the past i used Antcontrib a lot, but as it's development seems to be dead - last release back in 2006 - i've searched for a similar tool and found Ant Flaka (http://code.google.com/p/flaka/). Flaka has some very innovative features, f.e. an Expression Language similar to JSF/JSP

Comment: As described in my question, I wasn't sure how to use the <var> task with <loadfile>

Comment: You use var/unset to unset the property before calling loadfile a second time.

Answer (score 1):

One of the built-in tasks that are able to override the property value is `script`.

Below is a script and the output that proves the property value changed.

```
<project name="test">
  <property name="bshJar" value="C:\lang\java\bsh-1.3.0.jar:C:\lang\java\bsf.jar:C:\lang\java\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar" />
  <property name="a" value="first" />
  <echo>a=${a}</echo>
  <script manager="bsf" language="beanshell" classpath="${bshJar}"><![CDATA[
  project.setProperty("a", "fourth");
  ]]></script>
  <echo>a=${a}</echo>
</project>
```

Output:

```
a=first
a=fourth
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up using the `<unset>` task provided by Antelope
http://antelope.tigris.org/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the script in ANT.

```
<script language="javascript">
project.setProperty("my.property", "somevalue");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new property in your MacroDef for each srcFile:

```
<loadfile srcFile="@{some.input}" property="@{some.input}_Prop">

<echo message="@{some.input} Contents: ${@{some.input}_Prop}"/>
```