# Changing property value in Ant

Tags: ant

I don't want to use propertyregex in the [AntContrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) task, but I need to modify a property. I am using the `cabarc` command (I can't get the `<cab>` task to work), and I need to strip out the drive name.

```
${basedir} = "D:\some\directory\blah\blah"
${cwd} = some\directory\blah\blah"
```

I need this in order to strip out the path in cabarc (but still using directories). I've ended up doing the following:

```
<!-- Create a property set with just basedir -->
<!-- Needed for loadproperties to work -->

<propertyset id="cwd">
    <propertyref name="basedir"/>
</propertyset>

<loadproperties>
     <propertyset refid="cwd"/>
     <filterchain>
         <tokenfilter>
              <replaceregex pattern=".:\\"
                   replace="cwd="/>
         </tokenfilter>
     </filterchain>
</loadproperties>
```

That works, but it's a little complex and will be hard to maintain.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Other ways in a similar question: [Ant loadfile override property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358525/ant-loadfile-override-property/10717634#10717634)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get into the groove ;-)

```
<groovy>
properties.'cwd' = properties.'basedir'[3..-1]
</groovy>
```

or with [Ant Plugin Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) :

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka" name="World">
  <!-- simple echo -->
  <fl:echo>#{replace('${basedir}', '$1' , '.:\\\\(.+)' )}</fl:echo>
  <!-- set property -->
  <fl:let>cwd := replace('${basedir}', '$1' , '.:\\\\(.+)' )</fl:let>
</project>
```

Disclosure = i'm participating as committer in the Flaka project

Comment: I guess it's time to learn groovy. I don't want to use Ant Plugin Flaka for the same reason I don't want to use AntContrib if I don't have to.

Comment: you won't regret learning groovy. It's useful in ant as it has its own <groovy> task beside <script language=groovy> and you may also use ant from groovy via antbuilder. It's possible to create ant scripts with groovy - no xml required :-) And after all its pure Java, compiles to Java bytecode