# How can I use Java in an Ant buildfile?

Tags: java, javascript, ant

I'm trying to write a custom scriptselector, and to do so I need to read the contents of each file.

Is there a way to use java, and not javascript, as the language of a scriptselector? If not, is there a way, silly as it sounds, to read the File object?

```
<scriptselector language="javascript">
    f = self.getFile();
    println(f);
    //how to read the File?
    self.setSelected(true);
</scriptselector>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how. Something along the lines of:

```
<scriptselector language="javascript">
    importPackage(java.io);
    importPackage(org.apache.tools.ant.util);

    fileUtils = FileUtils.getFileUtils();
    f = self.getFile();
    println(f);
    if( f.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".xyz") ){
        fis = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());
        isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        println('reading it!');
        fileContents = fileUtils.readFully(isr);
        println(fileContents);
        self.setSelected(true);
    }
</scriptselector>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use any [BSF-supported language](http://jakarta.apache.org/bsf/), which includes BeanShell (Java).  For example:

```
<script language="beanshell">
    String file = "foo.txt";
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(file);
        // read from stream as required
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
            is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { /* ignore */ }
         }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I tried that initially but got the "Unable to create javax script engine for beanshell" error

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716646/beanshell-in-ant-yielding-unable-to-create-javax-script-engine-for-beanshell/2718861#2718861 for adding required jars to build configuration to eliminate that error.

Comment: Many thanks. If I can get that to work without adding it to ANT's classpath -- i.e. include that jar in my project and reference it in a classpathref -- then that's a winner.