# Using Ant, how do I open a file in a browser?

Tags: ant

I have an Ant task that creates an HTML report.  Is it possible to load that report automatically in a browser from the Ant task?  If so, is it possible to do so in a user-independent way or would it require the use of custom user properties?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using Ant's `exec` task to execute a system command.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

An example from that document:

```
<property name="browser" location="C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe"/>
<property name="file" location="ant/docs/manual/index.html"/>

<exec executable="${browser}" spawn="true">
    <arg value="${file}"/>
</exec>
```

Answer (score 8):

I used `<script>` with javascript:

```
<property name="mydirectory" location="target/report"/>

<script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
    location = "file:///"+project.getProperty("mydirectory").toString().replaceAll("\\\\","/")+"/index.html";
    java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(location));
]]></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

There is an independent way, like we do in java:

```
Desktop.getDesktop.open(new File("file.html")) ?
```

I see no exit without ant optional tasks. From all the scripts beanshell looks most lightweight and does not require any new knowledge. So I did it this way:

```
<property name="bshJar" value="
  C:\lang\java\bsh-1.3.0.jar:
  C:\lang\java\bsf.jar:
  C:\lang\java\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar" />
<script manager="bsf" language="beanshell" classpath="${bshJar}">
  java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(
    new java.io.File("c:\\temp\\1\\stackoverflow\\DVD FAQ.htm"));
</script>
```

And this is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12653680/772981) about getting `script` task running. However `javascript` language is indeed a better option, as it needs no `classpath` (and no `manager`) in JDK 6. And the code inside remains the same.

Answer (score 5):

I need a solution that is platform independent, so based upon "1.21 gigawatts" answer:

```
<scriptdef name="open" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="file" />
    <![CDATA[
        var location = "file://"+attributes.get("file").toString().replaceAll("\\\\","/");
        location = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(location, "UTF-8");
        location = location.toString().replace("%3A",":");
        location = location.toString().replace("%2F","/");
        println("Opening file " + location);
        var uriLocation = java.net.URI.create(location);
        var desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
        desktop.browse(uriLocation);
    ]]>
</scriptdef>
```

This can be called in ant with:

```
<open file="C:\index.html" />
```

Comment: In order to get this to work with Java 8 and Java 7 I had to (a) remove println (and echo the path from ant instead) and (b) instead of `location.toString().replace("%3A",":");` I used `location.toString().replaceAll("%3A",":");`

Answer (score 4):

How I did it:

In my build.properties

```
#Browser
browser = open
browser.args = -a Firefox
```

In my build.xml

```
<target name="openCoverage">
    <exec executable="${browser}" spawn="yes">
        <arg line="${browser.args}" />
        <arg line="${unit.html}" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Answer (score 3):

Basing this on Gabor's answer I had to do a few more things to get it to work. Here's my code:

```
    <!-- Build and output the Avenue.swf-->
    <target name="Open in browser" >
    <property name="myDirectory" location="BuildTest/bin-debug"/>

    <script language="javascript">
        <![CDATA[
            var location = "file:///"+project.getProperty("myDirectory").toString().replaceAll("\\\\","/")+"/BuildTest.html";
            location = location.toString().replace(/ /g, "%20");
             // show URL - copy and paste into browser address bar to test location
            println(location);
            var uriLocation = java.net.URI.create(location);
            var desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
            desktop.browse(uriLocation);
        ]]>
    </script>
</target>
```

I had to append the project name to the directory and replace the spaces with "%20". After that it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to invoke your favorite browser with the filename. If you have Ant execute

```
firefox "file:///G:/Report.html"
```

it will launch Firefox with that file.

Answer (score 1):

This opens the given HTML file in the **system-default browser** using only pure Ant.

```
<property name="report.file" value="${temp.dir}/report/index.html" />

<exec executable="cmd" spawn="yes">
    <arg value="/c" />
    <arg value="${report.file}" />
</exec>
```