# How Can I Start Jetty and open a Browser In Platform Independent Way

Tags: java, jsp, webserver, launcher, usb-flash-drive

I have a simple JSP web-page/site. I have installed Jetty on a Flash-Drive, and put the Jsp/Site into the root context. I have a batch file and when I click it, it starts jetty and then launches IE and the webpage starts up. I even have a JRE installed on the flash-drive in case it's not installed locally. Works great, less filling, eventually directs the user to the real website to do some real work.

What I'd like to do it make the flash-drive app more platform independent/compatible. I'd like to have an icon or icons for either a mac or unix or windows users to click on to start the web-server and then launch a browser. It would be nice to have different versions of the JVM installed so the program(s) could pick the right one for the machine their on.

I looked a little at Java Web Start, but it does not seem to be a good fit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `ant` as build system you can use solutions prosposed by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696176/using-ant-how-do-i-open-a-file-in-a-browser) post

Comment: I don't think most random platforms are going to have ant installed.

Comment: @CAMOBAP -- please do not simply edit tag wikis by providing a link; these are not helpful, and will result in being rejected.  Pleas put more effort into tag wiki entries.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/753806#./753806?&_suid=1349361627875013721106153570955