# Can i use .rar file in class path for a standalone Java program to pick up?

Tags: ibm-mq, rar

I have a standalone Java program which sends a message to MQ and receives a message. I need to use the wmq.jmsra.rar which has 10+ jar files in it. It works fine, if I unzip the rar and use jars in the classpath. I was wondering whether there is a way i can use this .rar file directly instead of unzipping it and adding each jar into classpath or adding the folder to classpath.

My question is related to this, but different... [Is it correct or incorrect for a Java JAR to contain its own dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662068/is-it-correct-or-incorrect-for-a-java-jar-to-contain-its-own-dependencies/12662966#12662966)

Thanks
Jugunu

Answer (score 0):

The Resource Adapter (wmq.jmsra.rar) should be used when configuring a JavaEE application server. Details on getting that are at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21633761

Please don't unzip this to get at the component parts; instead use the MQ Classes for JMS 'allclient' jar or the OSGi bundles. Information on how to get those are available at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21683398

Those technotes give information for the latest releases. The 'allclient' is a v8 statement only - however installation of the client support packs (eg MQC75) will give you access to the JMS client.

Comment: thanks much calanais, that worked.. I downloaded the 8.0.0.1-WS-MQ-Install-Java-All.jar from IBM site and used the jars from JavaSE folder. Also I had to remove j2ee.jar and change compiler settings to 1.6 to remove the version conflict.

Comment: Hi Calanais, i am facing a unique situation.. my code is not working in server due to this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javax/jms/JMSException : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0"

I am not allowed to upgrade the jre since there are many other app and the jre version is jdk1.6_45. the ibm jars are all compiled to "Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_09" (i checked the meta-inf)... Is there any work around for this issue.. I checked net and found the most used suggestion to just upgrade the jre.. With latest jre its working fine.. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Calanais, i got the go ahead for upgrading the jdk and testing the older applications.

Comment: MQ v8 implements JMS2.0 which has a requirement on Java 7. That error is telling you that the classfiles are compiled for Java7 but you've got a Java6 runtime. The option is to update the JRE as you've been able to do. 

Pleased you've got the update through.